# An application form in XML

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt-1.0

I have one challenging task. I want an application form that is in completely in XML 
(with xslt).Application having textbox,dropdown list, checkbox etc.

First of all user will download this application form (XML).then user fill this form.
when user fills this form the data should be stored locally. and when i upload this file to server, all the data will be saved in my database.

Is it possible ??

Comment: XML is just a markup language. It is a textual data format - it only stores text and that's it. It is not possible to have interact elements like checkboxes and dropdown lists. This is what web browsers and HTML is for. Or use Windows Forms or WPF for a Windows desktop application.

Comment: I see you have tagged ASP.NET for this post. Is that what you are using? If so, what is wrong with using ASP.NET Web Forms for implementing the form?

Comment: Actually my application is not windows application. I have a requirement from client that user would be able to download an application form fills that form and upload that form and data will be stored in database by reading this XML.

Answer (score 1):

This is recognized as a desirable feature. It makes sense that given an XML schema it should be possible to utilize this to take some of the development effort out of form filling and submission. The specification is known as **XForms**. I looked at this about ten years ago and it was really immature. I can only suggest that you google XForms and see if there are any toolkits that suits your needs. Otherwise you will have to hand code the functionality yourself. As far as I know the XForms specification is not supported directly in any browsers.